# Removing a line that ends with a " : " with vi (on AIX)

Tags: original-vi, search-replace

Very simply, I need to remove lines in a file that end with a `:`.

I've tried many things but have not managed it.  I cannot even find the right search pattern.

example line:

```
anbdskjhd:
```

I would like to delete the line since it ends with a `:`.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the character is special, the command `:g/:$/d` (abbreviated from `:global/:$/delete`) should do it.

Perhaps you meant the line ends with `":"`, in which case simply change `/:$/` to `/":"$/` in either command.